# Save repetitive rows to one txt file

Tags: r

I have this kind of df. I would like to generate txt with the name provided in column filename. Inside the txt file should be the values from numbers.

```
+----------+-------------+
| filename |   numbers   |
+----------+-------------+
| a.jpeg   | 129 292 010 |
| b.jpeg   | 838 828 929 |
| b.jpeg   | 838 939 191 |
| c.jpeg   | 999 838 737 |
+----------+-------------+
```

Now, if there are the same filenames I would like to generate such a txt:

Filename: b.jpeg
Inside the txt:

```
838 828 929 
838 939 191
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: `lst1 <- split(df1$numbers, df1$filename); lapply(names(lst1), function(nm) write.table(lst1[[nm]], file = paste0(nm1, ".txt")))`

Comment: Thanks! What is the nm1 object?

Comment: it is a typo, `nm`

Comment: Great! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can do a `split` into a `list` and then write it as different tables

```
lst1 <- split(df1$numbers, df1$filename)
lapply(names(lst1), function(nm) write.table(lst1[[nm]], file = paste0(nm, ".txt")))
```